# Rails: Collection_select saving IDs as one entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

I am trying to use collection_select instead of select.

```
<%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= tech.label :tech %><br />
    <%=  tech.select(:tech, Technol.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq,:prompt => "Select a previous role") %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

This code works, allowing me to link one technology to a project. I have tried to do this:

```
<%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= tech.label :tech %><br />
    <%= tech.collection_select(:tech,  Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} ) %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

The collection_select appears, and all the technologies are shown in the dropdown, and when I pick a few and submit the project, the technologies are shown as one entry, by their IDs.

`--- - '' - '11' - '12' - '13'`

Here is my create action, that I think is causing the problem:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

    params[:technol].each_value do |tech|

    technology = Technol.find_or_create_by_tech(tech)

    @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technology.id) 
end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I think it's some problem with the way I am looping. Hopefully someone can see it. I am new to rails so please remember this when trying to help me. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have tried changing the collection_select to:

```
<%=  tech.select(:technol, :id, Technol.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq,:prompt => "Select a previous role") %>
```

and I get this error. `wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)`

UPDATE for Ross:

```
wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)
Extracted source (around line #273):

273: tech.collection_select(:tech, :tech_ids, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {:prompt => "Select a previous role"}, {:multiple => true} )
```

Comment: I think its the syntax of collection select 
try

tech.collection_select(:tech, :tech_ids, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} )

Comment: Hi there, I get the same error as I got with the update in my question.

Comment: use proper brackets , try copy pasting the same as I commented above

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
collection_select(:test, :tech_ids, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {:prompt => "Select a previous role"}, {:multiple => true} )
```

Comment: I have just updated my question to show you what happens when I run your code. Cheers

Comment: I get a No method error. `undefined method "tech_ids" for #<Technol id: nil, tech: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`. So I changed it to just `:id`, and I get no technologies added to the project
`